# Scripting an input element of an HTML form?

Tags: javascript

By design I need an input element typed text but I do not need an input element typed submit. I want to submit what's written in the input element once the enter key pressed. How would I do that in JavaScript? Do I need tags  and other stuff or could I do it without them (just using )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox at least, pushing enter in a `input[type=text]` element will submit it.

Check it out on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oseso/edit).

You do not need to use JavaScript (maybe in IE, can not test that now).

Also, it's worth mentioning that all forms *should* have a submit button. You will need to explicitly tell the user to push enter. Also, what about devices with no enter button? I've heard the Zune can not submit forms without a button.

Some people say an exception is the search input box, like on Stack Overflow. However, I think it could still benefit from a small *search* button or similar.

Comment: I agree that a small button is to recommend.

Comment: Yeah, Alex, the search input box is what it will be. Also, I have looked at how it is implemented on SO - and no (even hidden) button I found there. (Though they have the form tags.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any script. I have a small hook for you

```
<form id="form" action="action.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="login" value="login" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

style="display: none;" is a solution

Comment: That might actually solve the disability and/or mobile problem, if you style the submit button with the @media selector.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need JavaScript for that. This should work across major desktop browsers (FF2-3,Chrome/Chromium,IE6-8,Opera6-10):

```
<form action="/some/action" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="somefield">
</form>
```

Pressing ENTER in the input field will submit the form as usual.

Caveats:

- (mouse) users will be confused - do you want to *create* a major usability problem?
- users with disabilities (e.g. using some sort of screen reader) might not be able to submit the form - if the company is in the US, now you have a *legal* problem to go with the usability problem
- mobile and/or exotic browsers may not be able to submit the form

Comment: That's funny about the cavets you are pointing out. Very funny. Well, a fat lot I care about those problems. Use normal computers with keyboards attached - and you're fine. As for users with disabilities, well, I don't deal with that kind of people, so... =)

Comment: If you don't want an answer, you better stop asking questions, then. Also, I've yet to see an iPhone with a keyboard attached. Many things are "a computer", these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the keypress event and read the keycode on the particular element and whenever you get the "Enter" key, you can fire the submit.

```
function GetKeyCode(e) {
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
    alert('Character was ' + character);
}
```

However most of the browsers post the form on the "Enter" key automatically.